# 22.04 cannot suspend my laptop

Tags: suspend, 22.04, freeze

On ubuntu 22.04 trying to suspend my laptop the system freezes .
The fans keeps spinning and it overheats , only thing possible is a hard reboot.
Probably the bug was introduced by an update, because i had this problem only for a week or so.
laptop with amd ryzen 5

anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: there are different ways to suspend, I have been for 4 years with Ryzen5 laptops (yes, more than one) . I have gotten different results. 
1. gnome menu, power off/logout, suspend
2, systemctl suspend
3. pm-susend (install pm-utils)
4. id closed on laptop method, tweaks, suspend when laptop lid is closed
5. editing sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf    for
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend

Comment: I also suspect that hibernate might need to be enabled as well to get suspend to works though I have not retested this. ie a swap file present. for no good reason if that is the case.

Comment: adding  
6. settings, power, automatic suspend 
7. settings power, power button action.

Comment: haha, I think I've got something here... after 4 years. I chased up my message here...https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427280/journal-recommending-to-set-psmouse-synaptics-intertouch-1
see if your "journal | grep touchpad" returns that recommendation

Comment: which I set and rebooted. then , for the first time, I was able to suspend with lid shut (note the logind.conf edits were needed for that) and one of the other methods, one other method did not resume. the bad news was on one reboot no touchpad. I had also disabled bluetooth and  webcam (though that did not stop the search for them taking up most of the journal entries ). power button method also works, that baby makes three.

Comment: should mention, I am on wayland. touchpad does not show with libinput list-devices

Comment: reverted to 'norm' .now the only method that works is pm-suspend. I set it in soders using  sudo visudo, and set a custom key for 'sudo pm-suspend'. good enough for now. perhaps the latest upgrade stuffed up the other methods, none of now which work, blank screen requiring reboot. also not using Wayland. touchpad not lost on resume.