# How to wake up touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, hibernate

my touchpad basically fails to wake up from sleep.

Then, if I close the laptop lid to hibernate and then open it up again, it will bring back the touchpad mostly.

I would like to know why this happens and how I can prevent it from happening again.

Please help?

Huawei Matebook X

Running Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: "sleep" is for processes. Systems can "suspend" (enter low power state, save context to RAM), or "hibernate" (save RAM and context to disk (swap) and enter a power off state). Which do you mean? [Edit] your question to add information, do not use Add comment.

Comment: See how your system detects and initializes your touchpad with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`, and see how it comes back from suspend/hibernate with `sudo journalctl  --since="-10 minutes"`

Comment: see if you have what I had in 'journatlctl | grep touchpad' and a suggestion to add to grub a parameter. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427280/journal-recommending-to-set-psmouse-synaptics-intertouch-1
  see other methods to suspend
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421394/22-04-cannot-suspend-my-laptop

Comment: bearing in mind, no touchpad waking for sleep for me too today. I also had a script to suspend, sleep the USB first before suspending, then wake up after resume.. that *might* be able to be done for the touchpad too.
 echo '1-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind; sleep 1 ; sudo pm-suspend  ;sleep 1 ; echo '1-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

Comment: note I was on Wayland. switching to Ubuntu the lid switch closed method did not work, at all the others did, without locking up touchpad.

Comment: have you tried pm-suspend method? this method is working for me now without losing the touchpad (touch wood)

Comment: said method is now not working, resumes immediately. see sudp pm-suspend --help for options. --quirk-s3-bios did work , then did not.

Comment: but then I killed nordvpn process and it worked again. are you running that one?