# journal recommending to set psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1

Tags: grub2, 22.04, amd-ryzen

journal is sa" psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN324e ETD0000 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org."

I dont mind putting that into my grub, and I do have a loss, not even in xinput, of touchpad sometimes, but might this have an impact on my main problem these days, which is loss of usb mouse/keyboard and lockups generally?

curious that all threads on this had set psmouse.synaptics_intertouch and no 1's

Comment: I did it, and no problems with that so far. too soon to tell if it stops my general lockups or loss of usb mouse/keyboard issues, but note it seems to have enabled several methods to suspend that had not prevously worked for me. see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421394/22-04-cannot-suspend-my-laptop

Comment: make it an answer please

Comment: too soon to tell..  today's reboot had no touchpad. I will wait a week or so to see. I normally use USB mouse and keyboard. plus I did a successful dist upgrade to 22.04 on the other laptop, might do this one as well and see.

Comment: vindicated in not making it an answer, only the pm-suspend method now works at all, the rest go to Limbo, unresponsive with black screen. perhaps it was the recent upgrades that reverted to 'norm;. I also set p,-suspend in sudoers (using sudo visudo) and a custom key to do 'sudp pm-suspend' . convenient enough without any working lid closed method working.

Comment: typos, no edit available     sudo pm-suspend